# Null pointer exception - driver null

Tags: java, selenium

I am starting learning Selenium in Java and I have a big obstacle.

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class FirstTest {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void driverSetup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
    }

    @After
    public void driverQuit() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void getMethod() {
        driver.get("http://google.pl");
    }

}
```

I don't know how to solve it because in "getMethod" the driver is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `WebDriver driver;` at the global level and then you are again defining and instantiating another `WebDriver driver` in the `driverSetup` method because of which the global driver never got instantiated.
You need to make a single line change in the `driverSetup` method and it would work.
Your `driverSetup` should be like:

```
@Before
public void driverSetup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
    // Instantiating the global driver here
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You have already defined an instance of *WebDriver* i.e. `driver` as a global instance as in:

```
WebDriver driver;
```

You can reuse the same instance in `@Before`, `@Test` and `@After`. So there is no need to declare any additional instace of *WebDriver* in  `@Before` as you did:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

---

### Solution

The solution will be to use the same global *WebDriver* instance as follows:

```
WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void driverSetup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/main/resources/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1280, 720));
}
```